# messy css indentation in vim

Tags: css, vim, text-editor, indentation

When editing an html file in vim, the indentation for css inside `style` tags is messy.

For instance, this is how it would indent this sample css code without any manual intervention to fix the indentation on my part:

```
    div.class
{
color: white;
       backgroung-color: black;
}
```

Why is this happening? how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

I experience the same problem, can't really help but I tend to do is `vi{` then `9<<` and finally `>>`.
I tried to find a good css indent, but none of the ones I tried seemed to work properly.

Answer (score 4):

This [indent script](https://gist.github.com/762326/bcbd35239db7f26447f1c2323037d20a5219471d) seems to work well (better).

Download it and stick it at `~/.vim/indent/css.vim`

You'll need the `filetype plugin indent on` line in your `.vimrc` file, too, as kamaji suggests.

Now if I could only get it working on .css.less files...

Comment: You saved my day (or rather my night :) ). Note that I put the file you're linking to under ~/.vim/index/css.vim instead of css.less and it works well (is there any reason to name it css.less whereas on the plugin's github page it's called css.vim?). Thanks anyway!

Comment: corrected question. Had "less" on the brain. I don't any more. I have SASS on the brain instead!

Comment: hi artful, for me, after adding the script file given in the link, tab press puts eight spaces.. is that configurable to just two spaces for one level of indentation...

Comment: @Madhavan, a bit late, but why do you press the tab? In order to indent in the insert mode it's much more convenient to press Ctrl-t/d to shift the line to the right/left

Answer (score 1):

Try using [this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2075) html filetype indent script instead. It has improved support for style tags. Javascript and CSS indent handling in HTML pages is known to be problematic with the html indentation in Vim. I've yet to find a script that does everything perfectly.

Comment: The page says under known bugs "sometimes `cindent()` thinks it is better to use zero indent for what follows", which is pretty much what my problem is.

Comment: I think the problem is that all these indent files fall back to cindent. It would be nice if someone wrote the entire thing from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem.

My solution was to edit (after backing up) the global 'vimrc' file and uncomment the following lines, by removing the double quotes at the start of each line:

```
"if has("autocmd")
"  filetype plugin indent on
"endif
```

I also had 'set cindent' in my local '~/.vimrc' file so I removed that.

Seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

One explanation might be that you have a mixture of TABs and spaces in the file.

(Although the appearance in the question may be more due to Markdown than anything else)

Comment: I don't have any hard TAB character (and why would it cause messy auto indentation anyway?)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem is because of `cindent`. Find the following line in your `.vimrc` (or `.gvimrc`, ...) and remove it.

```
set cindent
```

Then you are good to go. Lastly if you are both a web page developer and kernel developer you can perhaps use a mapping like bellow to toggle `cindent` on and off

```
map <F8> :set cindent!<CR>
```